# Shapefile From Excel Sheet Crash When Selected Spatialy or By Attributes

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute, excel, select-by-location

Using ArcGIS 10.2, I am receiving an Excel sheet, on a daily basis, which contains 105 columns(Fields) and includes has X and Y values.

For whatever reason (which I cannot understand) all data types in the sheet were formatted as "Currency" so I run a Macro to change all values reformat the field as:

"@", "0" , "0%" and finally "0.000000" for X and Y column before adding the sheet to ArcMap.

1. I use the Add Data --> Add XY Data... method to add the Sheet to ArcMap
2. I then Use Data--> Export Data --> all Features to export as a shapefile.

Now after the process shapefile automatically can be added to map I have all points on the map and the table shows all values which were in the Excel file BUT whenever I try to Select Points by Select Feature tool or Select From Table the ArcMap Crashes.

Selecting by Attributes also does not get any Unique values!

And finally after closing the map I am not able to add the shapefile into Map again.

Can you please let me know what may cause such an issue?

Comment: Does this crash occur even if you restart ArcMap and use a Blank Map?  If so, when ArcMap misbehaves like this I recommend performing a reboot, and re-trying again.  Any time you are offered the chance to send logs to Esri, I recommend doing so.  Would you be able to edit your Question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop you are using, please?

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and this only happen on using data from this excel sheet!

Comment: I would try taking some copies of your spreadsheet and deleting rows from them to try and identify if some rows work and others cause the issue.

Comment: Excel spreadsheets are notoriously flaky; are you *really* using ArcGIS 10.2? That's so old. I find it best to convert Excel into something else, a DBF or Geodatabase Table would be much more stable, especially when using as an XY event layer.